# Найти номер столбца и ряда элемента матрицы

Tags: java, матрицы

Есть матрица, нужно каждый элемент  вывести на экран а также вывести его ряд и столбец.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[][] mat = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
    int i = 0;
    int j;
    for (j = 0; j < mat.length; j++) {


        System.out.println("Element: " + mat[i][j] + "\n Ряд: " + i + "\n Столбец: " + j);
        i++;
    }

}
```

Выводит только для 1, 5 и 9, так как i и j увеличиваются на 1, не знаю как применить для каждого элемента.

Comment: Нужен еще один вложенный цикл

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все проще!

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    int[][] mass = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
    for (int i = 0; i < mass.length; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < mass.length; j++)
        {
            System.out.println(mass[i][j] + "\n Ряд: " + i + "\n Столбец: " + j);
        }
        System.out.println(""); //каждый раз переходим на новую строчку вывода


    }

}
```

Вывод:

```
1  
 Ряд: 0  
 Столбец: 0  
2  
 Ряд: 0  
 Столбец: 1  
3  
 Ряд: 0  
 Столбец: 2  

4  
 Ряд: 1  
 Столбец: 0  
5  
 Ряд: 1  
 Столбец: 1  
6  
 Ряд: 1  
 Столбец: 2  

7  
 Ряд: 2  
 Cтолбец: 0  
8  
 Ряд: 2  
 Столбец: 1  
9  
 Ряд: 2  
 Столбец: 2
```

Comment: `j < mass[i].length`

Comment: зачем? все же работает

Comment: это будет работать только в данном случаи. Но если массив неравномерный, то и работать то не будет

Comment: "Вы погубите себя, мой юный друг!" Александр Дюма

Comment: как вывод красиво оформить?

Comment: это ты диз поставил на вопрос?)

Comment: я видел это желтым делают. научишь? а так спасибо)

Comment: я походу неправильно сформулировал вопрос... нужно вывести ЗНАЧЕНИЕ элемента и НОМЕР ряда и НОМЕР столбца этого самого элемента

Comment: @Blooop, как вы себе это представляете?)

Comment: @МишаКотор представляю так как вы написали ответ, я это и имел ввиду